# Unknown MySQL syntax error during the WordPress installation

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install Wordpress on my local server according to instruction described on [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu)

And now I'm stuck on this step:

`GRANT ALL ON wordpress_db.* TO 'wp_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Tried this command replacing `'password'` with my actual password, but MySQL complains about an extra apostrophe at the end of a sentence, but I can't find any mistake.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON wordpress.* TO 'wp_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wordpress1sthebest';

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'wordpress1sthebest'' at line 1
```

Tried to run it also in phpMyAdmin,
[here is what i've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq4oE.png)

Please help

Comment: Think the entire `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` is extraneous. Try just `GRANT ALL ON wordpress_db.* TO 'wp_user'@'localhost';`

Comment: It is not extraneous.  Instead, the syntax has changed.

Comment: To be honest, I'd never seen the older syntax so I was assuming that the user was already created... I should have checked the instructions page, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of MySQL no longer allow that syntax.  It is now two steps:

```
CREATE USER ... IDENTIFIED BY ...;
GRANT ... TO ...;
```

Is there a newer version of WP?